# Create Action in Controller not hitting breakpoint in .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My *Create* action is not hitting the breakpoint. I have repaired my Visual Studio (2015) and made sure I am in debug mode. I cleaned and rebuilt a couple of times. I moved the source code to a new instance of VS. The PDB file is present.
I can hit a break point on other actions/methods except the create one, I am using *httppostedfilebase* to upload an image and a song.

When I create the error reads as follows:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

And here is my controller action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateSong([Bind(Include = "SongID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Rating,Poster,PosterFilePath,FileType,Audio,AudioFilePath,Likes,DisLikes,Faves,Reposts")] Song song, HttpPostedFileBase image, HttpPostedFileBase audio)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            song.Poster = new byte[image.ContentLength];
            song.Likes = 0;
            song.DisLikes = 0;
            song.Faves = 0;
            song.Reposts = 0;
            image.InputStream.Read(song.Poster, 0, image.ContentLength);
            var imgName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
            song.PosterFilePath = "../Uploads/Song/" + imgName;

           image.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/thumbnails/"), imgName));
        }

        SongLike songLike = new SongLike();
        songLike.Liked = false;
        songLike.LikedDate = DateTime.Today;
        songLike.SongLikeId = song.SongID;

        if (audio != null && audio.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var audName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(audio.FileName);
            var audExt = Path.GetExtension(audio.FileName);
            song.FileType = audExt;
            string path = "../Uploads/songs/" + audName + audExt;
            song.AudioFilePath = path;

            audio.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/songs/"), audName + audExt));

            string output = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/songs/" + audName + audExt);
        }

        db.Songs.Add(song);
        db.SongLikes.Add(songLike);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "ID", "Name", song.CategoryID);
    return View(song);
}
```

Comment: While you are runniing, do you see a red dot filled or an empty one?

Comment: filled. But it doesn't get the yellow but in the index action for instance it works  and I can inspect the object data.

Comment: Is Index inside  the same class?

Comment: yes, It is in the same controller class

Comment: strange...are you sure you are calling it correctly and the CreateSong runs (despite it does not stops) ?

Comment: It  gives me a base64 encoding error (the one I mentioned above), I am sure I am calling it in the front end I can post my front end if you would like to see it.I first saw the encodinig error before I saw that the breakpoints are not being hit.

Comment: which line is throwing that error? The stack trace should tell you, even if your debugging environment is not working fully.

Comment: Can you show the model structure & show the line which throwing exception? Sounds like the model binder messed up with `Include` bound objects and passed invalid Base64 encoded string instead of its proper format, I suggest you to use strongly typed viewmodel.

Comment: Try placing [HttpPost] on top of that action. But it would be better if you showed us the view as well.

Comment: HttpPost is there and the error only reads as above, it does not give a line number. This is what lead me to discovering that the break point is not working. I apologise for not responding sooner.

Comment: The model structure is the same as the model binding,The line with the error is not being given in the error or the stack trace, I cannot write the stack trace out.